# Cannot reference static class from asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class called Helper in an asp.net web app and I cannot seem to reference it from the web forms.

The Helper.cs file looks like this:

```
using System;
....

namespace WebApp
{

    public static class Helper
    {
     ....
    }
}
```

If I try to add `using WebApp.Helper;` to the Default.aspx.cs for example it says it cannot find it. Must I add a new project and reference it that way?

Comment: Your `Helper` class is not in the namespace `DCSTools` - or is that a typo?

Comment: Your namespace is `WebApp` so, assuming you're in the same project, your using statement should be `using WebApp;`

Comment: Web *application* or web *site*? There's a big difference between the two - in a website, all code like this would have to be in the `App_Code` directory. Also, using works with the namespace, i.e. `using WebApp;`, not `using WebApp.Helper;`

Comment: If you try from another page calling WebApp.Helper.Method1(), it won't allow you to access it? Intellisense does not show you the class after writing the namespace WebApp?

Comment: Your using statement should be `using WebApp;` but make sure that you have referenced your project in your web app

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. It is set to WebApp but it still does not find it.

Comment: @sd_dracula Is it in separate `Project` (Like `ClassLibrary` project).

Comment: No it is just a class file. But I have managed to fix it somehow. Deleting and recreating fixed it. For no reason but oh well it works anyway.